# how to prevent change detection when an event fired while using 'changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush'?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

I have a getter property with some complex calculations and inorder to prevent unnecessary `changeDetections` I changed to `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `OnPush`.

**Even After using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` the `getter` gets executed on every possible events fired in the view like `button clicks`.**

And this is causing some serious performance issues in my app. Is there any way to disable the changedetection and trigger it only when needed ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very vague, as you don't provide any code sample. For this reason it is really difficult to find a reason, why `onPush`strategy doesn't work for your case. I would advice comparing your code against examples of common pitfalls mentioned [in this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/).

You might also consider implementing [onChanges() lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges) and manually define cases, for which change computations should take a place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I solved it using observable instead of getters.